# Filter DataFrame row by hour

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Python 3.6 here. I have a DataFrame that I reduce to 2 columns, the text and the date (type datetime). I'm trying to filter by row where it's a certain hour with this code :

```
import pandas as pd

laDataBrute = {'timestamp':['1519245127727', '1519246924475'], 
        'date creation': ['Wed Feb 21 20:32:07 +0000 2018', 'Wed Feb 21 21:02:04 +0000 2018' ], 
        'texte':['GE CFO says no plans for an equity raise', 'Baker Hughes rises after GE CFO signals plans']}
laDataBrute = pd.DataFrame(laDataBrute)

laDataBrute['date creation'] = pd.to_datetime(laDataBrute['timestamp'], unit='ms')
resultat = laDataBrute.loc[laDataBrute["texte"].str.contains(r'\bGE\b', regex=True) &
                           laDataBrute["date creation"].dt.hour == 21, 
                           ["texte","date creation"]]
print(resultat)
```

Here is the ouput :

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [texte, date creation]
Index: []
```

Don't know what i did wrong, thanks !

Comment: [MCVE] please...!

Comment: Can you try running the .loc with only the first condition: laDataBrute["texte"].str.contains(r'\bGE\b', regex=True)?

I can't tell what this is filtering on based on your example and it would help to isolate the problem.

Comment: Or only the second, hour-based one I'd say...

Comment: Sorry, I've changed the code with a little df which displays the same output. I tried with only the filter on text and only the filter on hour and it works in both case

Comment: Ok found it, just had to add parenthesis around each test !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parathesis:

```
laDataBrute['texte'].str.contains(r'\bGE\b') & (laDataBrute["date creation"].dt.hour == 21)
```

Output:

```
0    False
1     True
dtype: bool
```

Versus what you had:

```
laDataBrute['texte'].str.contains(r'\bGE\b') & laDataBrute["date creation"].dt.hour == 21
```

Output:

```
0    False
1    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: I'm surprised you don't get the usual warning though (that's usually how I spot these).

Comment: Good question, i'm working with Spyder 3.1 and there is no warning without the parenthesis. Maybe I have to change some settings to spot those mistakes.